# Приложение C#, WPF, .NET 6: Как увеличить размер стека

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, clr, .net-6

Я разрабатываю игру на WPF. Но как запускаю приложение, оно зависает и новая оперативная память не выделяется. Я использую .NET 6 и WPF.
Я думаю в приложении .NET не хватает памяти стека.

Вопрос в том, как програмно управлять Доменом приложения в CLR, чтобы увеличить его стек?

Comment: Крайне маловероятно, что зависает из-за размера кучи, ибо ограничения на размер кучи просто не существует. Ищите причину в чем то другом, попробуйте остановить программу под отладчиком в момент зависания и посмотрите, какие потоки висят на каком вызове.

Comment: + Вопросы с отладкой кода в репозитории запрещены. Код должен быть минимальным, и его нужно включать в сам вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Так ответьте на вопрос в общем: Как программно или в настройках проекта увеличить размер стека и как увеличить размер кучи програмы, програмно или в настройках проекта.

Comment: В таких ситуациях следует не размер стека пытаться увеличить, а сократить его потребление.

Comment: Основной вопрос, как увеличить размер кучи, программно или в настройках проекта. Проект на .NET 6. Программа замерзает, когда оперативная память подходит к 120 МБ в оперативной памяти.

Comment: Проблемы с черезмерным потреблением памяти не решить путем увеличения ее количества. "у меня происходит переполнение стека" и "программа виснет" это две несвязанные ошибки. Если у вас две разных проблемы, то следует создать два разных вопроса. В любом случае, необходимо предоставить [mcve].

Comment: Пример я предоставить не могу, т.к. вопрос у меня вообщем, как увеличить, размер кучи, если программа зависает с выделением памяти на 120МБ, хотя оперативки 8ГБ. Возможно это делается в настройках проекта. Пожалуйста, дайте вопросу повисеть, возможно, кто-то ответит, когда .NET 6 разрвьёт документацию.

Comment: Все таки стека или кучи? Размер стека задается флагом в бинарнике: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556970/8674428 , а про ограничение на размер кучи я ничего не слышал. Скорее всего, она ограничена только доступным объемом памяти, либо, при запуске под докером, лимитами докер-контейнера.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я хотел узнать, как его задать при компиляции, но это не особо важно, основное, как также задать размер кучи.

Comment: У вас ошибки в алгоритме (например, не обязательно использовать рекурсию) и в реализации (например, большой объем переменных в рекурсивной процедуре). Про размер кучи забудьте, дело не в этом.

Comment: Хороший способ на практике увидеть максимальный размер кучи, это в цикле выделять новые массивы (вроде `list.Add(new byte[1000]);`). Профилировщиком посмотреть память процесса, почти наверняка она будет расти, пока не исчерпается доступная ОЗУ на машине.

Comment: Если вы уперлись в стандартный размер стека, значит что-то пошло не так. Любая рекурсия может быть оптимизирована либо с использованием обычного стека `Stack<T>`, либо вообще с помощью цикла. У меня много приложений, работающих с данными, которые в процессе работы потребляют до 1 ГБ оперативы. Ничего специального для этого я не делал, оно просто работает. Проблема не в куче.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для увеличения стека мне помогло:

Самый простой способ установить размер стека начиная с .NET 2.0 и Win XP - создать новый поток с желаемым размером стека:

```
using System.Threading;

Thread T = new Thread(threadDelegate, stackSizeInBytes);
T.Start();
```

Чтобы изменить размер стека всей программы, вам придется использовать editbin:

```
EDITBIN.EXE /STACK:<stacksize> file.exe
```

*(Перевод [ответа Andrew O'Reilly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556970/8674428))*

Это помогло мне, программа больше не зависает, только долго работает.

Comment: При использовании чужих ответов нужно указывать ссылку на источник (я добавил правкой)

Comment: Спасибо, да по ГК нужно указвать источник заимствования.

Comment: _только долго работает_ - ваш код безобразно работает с ресурсами и создает тонны мусора. Нужно профилировать и отлаживать, а не стек увеличивать.

Comment: @aepot
Ну уж такой алгоритм и процессор... Я писал код из обобщений, т.к. алгоритмы мне показались интересными. Я писал ИИ, поэтому так долго работает. Если писать хардкод шахматных ходов, то работать будет быстрее.

Comment: @DmitriySidyakin написано очень неоптимально, это можно ускорить в разы. Начните с того. что нужно убрать `GC.Collect();`, это тормозит код.

Answer (score 0):

В C# объём памяти выделенный под кучу динамический расширяется при необходимости в автоматическом режиме. Впрочем, память под процесс даёт система, так что если и увеличивать количество памяти - то увеличивать количество памяти со стороны системы (для процесса), а не со стороны кода приложения.
Ну а вообще зависание приложения - это нетипичное поведение при нехватке памяти, так что рекомендую используя отладчик узнать где конкретно программа зависает, ну или профилировщик памяти (например [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/dotmemory/)).

Comment: Странно, я использую .NET 6 и приложение просто зависает на 160 МБ, а у меня их 8ГБ.

Comment: @DmitriySidyakin где конкретно виснет программа? В какой момент?

Comment: Программа виснет, если в настройках выбрать Компьютерного игрока и он делает ход

Comment: @DmitriySidyakin я при попытке создать игру с компьютером получаю всплывающее окно с надписью `ComputerPlayerIsNotAvailiableNow`

Comment: Вы должны залить код из ветки https://github.com/DmitriySidyakin/Chess/tree/Chess-0.1.2-with-Computer-Player-development , а не main

Comment: @DmitriySidyakin
Ругается на: `using GraphAlgorithms.Graph;`
Поскольку: `Project file 'C:\Users\ellen\RiderProjects\Graph\GraphAlgorithms\GraphAlgorithms.csproj' not found.`
Ну и я не вижу этого проекта в гите, может вы его в индекс не добавили?

Comment: Этот проект можно загрузить из https://github.com/DmitriySidyakin/Graph